# Reference assembly with different names, depending of the configuration

Tags: c#, csproj

I'm building a class library than can interact with different version of a product.

Each version of the product ship a SDK dll with a different assembly name: `MyProduct.V1.DLL`, `MyProduct.V2.Dll` and so on.

In my class library project, I try to play with configuration to be able to reference one at a time these assemblies. I basically mimic the product versioning scheme by creating these configurations :

- `DebugV1|Any CPU` to match the V1 version with debug compilation
- `ReleaseV1|Any CPU` to match the V1 version with release compilation
- `DebugV2|Any CPU` to match the V2 version with debug compilation
- `ReleaseV2|Any CPU` to match the V2 version with release compilation

I also tweaked the csproj file to generate the assembly name dynamically:

```
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'DebugV1|AnyCPU' ">
    <MyProductVersion>V1</MyProductVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'ReleaseV1|AnyCPU' ">
   <MyProductVersion>V1</MyProductVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'DebugV2|AnyCPU' ">
    <MyProductVersion>V2</MyProductVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'ReleaseV2|AnyCPU' ">
   <MyProductVersion>V2</MyProductVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
<ItemGroup>
  <Reference Include="MyProduct.$(MyProductVersion)">
    <HintPath>c:\Path\to\sdk\MyProduct.$(MyProductVersion).dll</HintPath>
  </Reference>
</ItemGroup>
```

I also tried the condition the full reference node :

```
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'DebugV1|AnyCPU' ">
    <ItemGroup>
       <Reference Include="MyProduct.V1">
  <HintPath>c:\Path\to\sdk\MyProduct.V1.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

None of these tries worked. The solution explorer always shows the V1 name in the reference node. The reference has the small warning icon telling me the reference is not found (which is probably because the HintPath is working)

Is it possible ? how can I make it works ?

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27494204/).

Comment: @NightOwl888: thx, your link was useful, because it allowed me to not stress when seeing warning icon